# How to migrate data from local storage to CosmosDB Table API?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, azcopy, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I tried following the documentation where I'm able to migrate data from Azure Table storage to Local storage but after that when I'm trying migrating data from Local to Cosmos DB Table API, I'm facing issues with destination endpoint of Table API. Anyone have the idea that  which destination endpoint to use? right now I'm using Table API endpoint from overview section.
[cmd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAOHY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem I see here is you are not using the Table name correctly in source. **TablesDB** is not the table name. Please check the screenshot below for what we should use for table name. (In this case, ***mytable1*** is the table name). So your source should be something like:

***/Source:C:\myfolder\ /Dest:https://xxxxxxxx.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/mytable1/***

[image]

Just re-iterating that I followed below steps and was able to migrate successfully:

1. Export from Azure Table Storage to local folder using below article. The table name should match the name of table in storage account:

   ***AzCopy /Source:https://xxxxxxxxxxx.table.core.windows.net/myTable/ /Dest:C:\myfolder\ /SourceKey:key***

[Export data from Table storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#export-data-from-table-storage)

2. Import from local folder to Azure Cosmos DB table API using below command where table name is the one we created in the azure cosmos db table api, destkey is primary key and source is exactly copied from connection string appended with table name

   ***AzCopy /Source:C:\myfolder\ /Dest:https://xxxxxxxx.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/mytable1//DestKey:key /Manifest:"myaccount_mytable_20140103T112020.manifest" /EntityOperation:InsertOrReplace***

Output:
[image]